New blower motor has no brown wires
My new motor does not have the 2 brown wires for the capacitor. Although it does require it. The new motor has a black and a yellow wire. The unit has a purple and a black wire that connected to the old motor. Do I connect the yellow and black to each side of the capacitor and then do the same with the purple and black wire?

What do the instructions say?  There should be a wiring diagram on the motor or in the instructions.  Without that, it is just a wild guess what wires go where.  There are 1000s of motors.

Model MOT18975. No diagram. Just says capacitor between black and yellow leads. That's why I was thinking the capacitor connects to the black and yellow wires and to the black and purple from the unit.

Between black and yellow leads seems to be the answer.  What instructions say, is usually what you go by.

I was just looking for a little more guidance from the manufacturer as for the common and power wires coming from the unit.

If the unit is listed by a recognize electrical testing lab like UL/CSA, then you obey the instructions.  Those instructions can override most electrical codes, almost like god said so.  Usually with capacitors and most other AC voltage, which wire on which connection(of two) usually does not matter, just use the right two wires.

If it's the same as the pictures I'm seeing online of Trane MOT18975 there is a diagram on the side of the motor. Follow that diagram. From the photos it looks like the capacitor goes between black and yellow, and line power goes between black and one of the three taps on the side. But don't believe me, believe the diagram on the motor. If there is no diagram on the motor, return it for a replacement that has the diagram on it. And if you bough it from A---z--, it might be a knockoff, which would explain the missing diagram. Return it and buy from a real supplier that doesn't mix counterfeits in with real stock.

